# create excel charts in separate sheet using vba

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, charts, microsoft-excel-2016

In Excel 2016, I am trying to write a vba sub that takes a worksheet containing some data and creates a new sheet which will be filled with charts that use the data in the original sheet.

I have recorded some macros and tried to use that to write my code. So far I have been able to create the charts on the same sheet as the data all stacked on top of each other.

I would like to have the charts populate a separate page and have them be spaced out in some way so they aren't blocking one another.
I believe this would involve not using ActiveSheet which the macro recorder typically uses.

I have posted my code below and would appreciate any help.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
'Measure A pair for A signal
Range("A:A,B:B,C:C,D:D,E:E").Select
    Range("E1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLine).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range( _
        "TEST!$B:$B,TEST!$C:$C,TEST!$D:$D,TEST!$E:$E")
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=TEST!$A2:$A1179"
'Measure B pair for A signal
Range("A:A,B:B,C:C,D:D,E:E").Select
    Range("E1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLine).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range( _
        "TEST!$F:$F,TEST!$G:$G,TEST!$H:$H,TEST!$I:$I")
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=TEST!$A2:$A1179"
End Sub
```

The sheet containing the data is called "TEST"

Comment: You are indeed correct and generally want to avoid using `Active` and `Select`. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) should get you started.

Comment: Don't use Select or ActiveSheet and don't build up the string address, use ranges directly. You may use Set chtChart = CurSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=75, Width:=300, Top:=75, Height:=300).Chart , will help you to put some space around it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would be useful to anyone but here is my final code that I ended up with:

```
Private Sub GraphButton1_Click()

Dim lngcount As Long
Dim filePath As String
Dim file_array As New Collection
'Open the file dialog'
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .Show

    'Display paths of each file selected'
    For lngcount = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
        filePath = .SelectedItems(lngcount)
        If Dir(filePath) <> "" Then
            Workbooks.Open (filePath)
            file_array.Add filePath
        End If
    Next lngcount
End With

Dim f As Variant
For Each f In file_array


'fileName is filename plus extension'
Filename = Dir(f)

'Create Workbook Object for TEST_DATA'
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Application.Workbooks(Filename)

'wsName is fileName without extension'
Dim wsName As String
wsName = Left(Filename, Len(Filename) - 4)

'Create Worksheet Object for TEST'
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
'Add chartsheet to workbook and create Worksheet Object for chartsheet'
wb.Worksheets.Add().Name = "chartsheet"
Dim chartsheet As Worksheet
Set chartsheet = wb.Worksheets("chartsheet")

'Measure A pair for A signal'
Dim chart1 As Chart
Set chart1 = chartsheet.Shapes.AddChart2.Chart

With chart1
    .Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="chartsheet"
    .ChartType = xlLine
    .SetSourceData Source:=Sheets(wsName).Range("$B:$B,$C:$C,$D:$D,$E:$E")
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = Sheets(wsName).Range("$A2:$A1179")
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = "A pair for A signal"
    .HasLegend = True
    .ChartArea.Left = 10
    .ChartArea.Top = 10
End With

'Measure B pair for A signal'
Dim chart2 As Chart
Set chart2 = chartsheet.Shapes.AddChart2.Chart
With chart2
    .Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="chartsheet"
    .ChartType = xlLine
    .SetSourceData Source:=Sheets(wsName).Range("$F:$F,$G:$G,$H:$H,$I:$I")
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = Sheets(wsName).Range("$A2:$A1179")
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = "B pair for A signal"
    .HasLegend = True
    .ChartArea.Left = 380
    .ChartArea.Top = 10
End With

'Measure C pair for A signal'
Dim chart3 As Chart
Set chart3 = chartsheet.Shapes.AddChart2.Chart
With chart3
    .Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="chartsheet"
    .ChartType = xlLine
    .SetSourceData Source:=Sheets(wsName).Range("$J:$J,$K:$K,$L:$L,$M:$M")
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = Sheets(wsName).Range("$A2:$A1179")
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = "C pair for A signal"
    .HasLegend = True
    .ChartArea.Left = 750
    .ChartArea.Top = 10
End With

'Measure D pair for A signal'
Dim chart4 As Chart
Set chart4 = chartsheet.Shapes.AddChart2.Chart
With chart4
    .Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="chartsheet"
    .ChartType = xlLine
    .SetSourceData Source:=Sheets(wsName).Range("$N:$N,$O:$O,$P:$P,$Q:$Q")
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = Sheets(wsName).Range("$A2:$A1179")
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = "D pair for A signal"
    .HasLegend = True
    .ChartArea.Left = 1120
    .ChartArea.Top = 10
End With

'Measure B pair for B signal'
Dim chart5 As Chart
Set chart5 = chartsheet.Shapes.AddChart2.Chart
With chart5
    .Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="chartsheet"
    .ChartType = xlLine
    .SetSourceData 
Source:=Sheets(wsName).Range("$AN:$AN,$AO:$AO,$AP:$AP,$AQ:$AQ")
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = Sheets(wsName).Range("$A2:$A1179")
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = "B pair for B signal"
    .HasLegend = True
    .ChartArea.Left = 10
    .ChartArea.Top = 240
End With

'Measure A pair for B signal'
Dim chart6 As Chart
Set chart6 = chartsheet.Shapes.AddChart2.Chart
With chart6
    .Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="chartsheet"
    .ChartType = xlLine
    .SetSourceData 
Source:=Sheets(wsName).Range("$AJ:$AJ,$AK:$AK,$AL:$AL,$AM:$AM")
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = Sheets(wsName).Range("$A2:$A1179")
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = "A pair for B signal"
    .HasLegend = True
    .ChartArea.Left = 380
    .ChartArea.Top = 240
End With

'Measure C pair for B signal'
Dim chart7 As Chart
Set chart7 = chartsheet.Shapes.AddChart2.Chart
With chart7
    .Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="chartsheet"
    .ChartType = xlLine
    .SetSourceData 
Source:=Sheets(wsName).Range("$AR:$AR,$AS:$AS,$AT:$AT,$AU:$AU")
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = Sheets(wsName).Range("$A2:$A1179")
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = "C pair for B signal"
    .HasLegend = True
    .ChartArea.Left = 750
    .ChartArea.Top = 240
End With

'Measure D pair for B signal'
Dim chart8 As Chart
Set chart8 = chartsheet.Shapes.AddChart2.Chart
With chart8
    .Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="chartsheet"
    .ChartType = xlLine
    .SetSourceData 
Source:=Sheets(wsName).Range("$AV:$AV,$AW:$AW,$AX:$AX,$AY:$AY")
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = Sheets(wsName).Range("$A2:$A1179")
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = "D pair for B signal"
    .HasLegend = True
    .ChartArea.Left = 1120
    .ChartArea.Top = 240
End With

'Measure C pair for C signal'
Dim chart9 As Chart
Set chart9 = chartsheet.Shapes.AddChart2.Chart
With chart9
    .Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="chartsheet"
    .ChartType = xlLine
    .SetSourceData 
Source:=Sheets(wsName).Range("$BZ:$BZ,$CA:$CA,$CB:$CB,$CC:$CC")
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = Sheets(wsName).Range("$A2:$A1179")
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = "C pair for C signal"
    .HasLegend = True
    .ChartArea.Left = 10
    .ChartArea.Top = 470
End With

'Measure A pair for C signal'
Dim chart10 As Chart
Set chart10 = chartsheet.Shapes.AddChart2.Chart
With chart10
    .Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="chartsheet"
    .ChartType = xlLine
    .SetSourceData 
Source:=Sheets(wsName).Range("$BR:$BR,$BS:$BS,$BT:$BT,$BU:$BU")
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = Sheets(wsName).Range("$A2:$A1179")
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = "A pair for C signal"
    .HasLegend = True
    .ChartArea.Left = 380
    .ChartArea.Top = 470
End With

'Measure B pair for C signal'
Dim chart11 As Chart
Set chart11 = chartsheet.Shapes.AddChart2.Chart
With chart11
    .Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="chartsheet"
    .ChartType = xlLine
    .SetSourceData 
Source:=Sheets(wsName).Range("$BV:$BV,$BW:$BW,$BX:$BX,$BY:$BY")
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = Sheets(wsName).Range("$A2:$A1179")
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = "B pair for C signal"
    .HasLegend = True
    .ChartArea.Left = 750
    .ChartArea.Top = 470
End With

'Measure D pair for C signal'
Dim chart12 As Chart
Set chart12 = chartsheet.Shapes.AddChart2.Chart
With chart12
    .Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="chartsheet"
    .ChartType = xlLine
    .SetSourceData 
Source:=Sheets(wsName).Range("$CD:$CD,$CE:$CE,$CF:$CF,$CG:$CG")
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = Sheets(wsName).Range("$A2:$A1179")
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = "D pair for C signal"
    .HasLegend = True
    .ChartArea.Left = 1120
    .ChartArea.Top = 470
End With

'Measure D pair for D signal'
Dim chart13 As Chart
Set chart13 = chartsheet.Shapes.AddChart2.Chart
With chart13
    .Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="chartsheet"
    .ChartType = xlLine
    .SetSourceData 
Source:=Sheets(wsName).Range("$DL:$DL,$DM:$DM,$DN:$DN,$DO:$DO")
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = Sheets(wsName).Range("$A2:$A1179")
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = "D pair for D signal"
    .HasLegend = True
    .ChartArea.Left = 10
    .ChartArea.Top = 700
End With

'Measure A pair for D signal'
Dim chart14 As Chart
Set chart14 = chartsheet.Shapes.AddChart2.Chart
With chart14
    .Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="chartsheet"
    .ChartType = xlLine
    .SetSourceData 
Source:=Sheets(wsName).Range("$CZ:$CZ,$DA:$DA,$DB:$DB,$DC:$DC")
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = Sheets(wsName).Range("$A2:$A1179")
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = "A pair for D signal"
    .HasLegend = True
    .ChartArea.Left = 380
    .ChartArea.Top = 700
End With

'Measure B pair for D signal'
Dim chart15 As Chart
Set chart15 = chartsheet.Shapes.AddChart2.Chart
With chart15
    .Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="chartsheet"
    .ChartType = xlLine
    .SetSourceData 
Source:=Sheets(wsName).Range("$DD:$DD,$DE:$DE,$DF:$DF,$DG:$DG")
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = Sheets(wsName).Range("$A2:$A1179")
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = "B pair for D signal"
    .HasLegend = True
    .ChartArea.Left = 750
    .ChartArea.Top = 700
End With

'Measure C pair for D signal'
Dim chart16 As Chart
Set chart16 = chartsheet.Shapes.AddChart2.Chart
With chart16
    .Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="chartsheet"
    .ChartType = xlLine
    .SetSourceData 
Source:=Sheets(wsName).Range("$DH:$DH,$DI:$DI,$DJ:$DJ,$DK:$DK")
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = Sheets(wsName).Range("$A2:$A1179")
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = "C pair for D signal"
    .HasLegend = True
    .ChartArea.Left = 1120
    .ChartArea.Top = 700
End With



Next f

End Sub
```

Obviously this probably wont be directly applicable to other people's projects but hopefully pieces of it can be helpful since the code includes opening files and creating objects for the worksheets in those files